# In Sitecore CDP, why is my guest appearing as anonymous at the top of the guest profile?

Tags: cdp

After sending in a successful identity event in `Sitecore CDP` my guest is still appearing as anonymous at the top of the guest profile. Why is this happening?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tenant you are using is storing personally identifiable information (PII), e.g. first name, last name, date of birth, address, etc, then the guest’s name will be displayed on the top of the guest profile dashboard. If PII is being stored in the tenant and the guest’s name is not available, then anonymous will be displayed on the top of the guest profile.

In the scenario shown the guest has been identified using their email. Once the guest was identified, the guest moved from an unknown visitor to a known customer. However, the guest’s name is not populated in the CDP. Therefore the guest is identified, but the guest’s name ism missing to fully populate the UI.

Depending on whether the tenant you are using is storing personally identifiable information (PII) or not, the data that is shown at the top of the guest profile will either a name, or an identifier.